# Is that possible to cast screen/app instead of media?

Tags: android, react-native, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

is that possible to cast screen/app with google cast/chromecast. I found option to cast media but i can't found how to cast whole app screen with google cast. is there any way to cast screen instead of media.

I need help in react-native or android development.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share your app screen with google Chromecast, but you can do something like this:

Receiver Web App

- create a Chromecast receiver web app https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver
- cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance().getCastMessageBus( to get message from sender and do something inside receiver
- cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance().broadcast( to send message to sender and do something inside sender
- set disableIdleTimeout = true to your web app not closing https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.CastReceiverOptions
- add new application on https://cast.google.com

Sender

- create a sender app example
  https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender
  https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender
  https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender
- send custom messages to receiver
- get custom messages from receiver

Have fun \o\